# Selenium Python - how to press enter in OS popup window

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, keyboard, pyautogui

I am automating a workflow with a number of actions in a website using Selenium for Python with the Firefox browser.

When I get to a point where I am using my personal certificate to authenticate, there is a window popup like this one (I have removed personal details). I just want to automate the action of pressing "enter"

[image]

Since it is not an html window, how can I use python to press "enter"?

I think this is not an html window, but rather an OS window so  as far as I know Selenium cannot access such window, so I have tried with two Python libraries, pyautogui and the keyboard module,
In the case os keyboard, giving the instruction:

```
keyboard.send("enter")
```

In the alternative of pyautogui, using:

```
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

None of these solutions have worked.

The environment I am using:

Python 3.9
OSX 12.3
Firefox 102.0.1 64 bits

I appreciate any hint to solve it.

Thank you in advance,

Ignacio

Comment: You are correct that Selenium cannot interact with a native popup.  With `pyautogui`, have you tried to move the mouse there and click?

Comment: pywinauto will also work if its pure windows popup and not the browser popup, Did you also tried the `alert()` from selenium api?

Comment: Thank you @C.Peck. I tried with `pyautogui` mouse click and it does not work. It seems like all python execution is halted by the operating system window...

Comment: @Dev I tried `alert()` but did not work. It seems that python execution is halted while OS window alert is open

Answer (score 0):

My workaround solution has been to use Safari's webdriver instead of Firefox. With Safari the above mentioned OS window does not appear at all, and my certificate is automatically selected in the background, so I don't even have the issue of pressing enter.

It would be appreciated nevertheless if someone comes with the solution for Firefox.